# PHP | Updating array items through function while iterating - Big performance issue

Tags: php, arrays

i am iterating an array with more than 3000 items in it
array looks something like that:

```
[
  [
    'id' => 1,
    'type' => 'income'
    'amount' => 10
  ],

  [
    'id' => 2,
    'type' => 'expense',
    'amount' => 20
  ],
  .......  
]
```

while iterating i call functions that manipulate another array in the same class
something like that:

```
$this->data->revenue->each(function($row) use($user)
{
    if ($row->isIncome())
    {
        $this->addRevenueRowToColumn($row, 'income'); 
        $this->addRevenueRowToColumn($row, 'total'); 
    }

    if ($row->isExpense())
    {
        $this->addRevenueRowToColumn($row, 'expense'); 
        $this->subtractRevenueRowToColumn($row, 'total'); 
    }
}
```

this is what the functions do:

```
protected function addRevenueRowToColumn(&$row, $columnName)
{
    $this->report['byMonth'][$row->getMonthTableKey()]['byDepartment'][$row->department_id][$columnName] += $row->amount;
    $this->report['byMonth'][$row->getMonthTableKey()]['total'][$columnName] += $row->amount;
    $this->report['totals']['byDepartment'][$row->department_id][$columnName] += $row->amount;
    $this->report['totals']['total'][$columnName] += $row->amount;
}

protected function subtractRevenueRowToColumn(&$row, $columnName)
{
    $this->report['byMonth'][$row->getMonthTableKey()]['byDepartment'][$row->department_id][$columnName] -= $row->amount;
    $this->report['byMonth'][$row->getMonthTableKey()]['total'][$columnName] -= $row->amount;
    $this->report['totals']['byDepartment'][$row->department_id][$columnName] -= $row->amount;
    $this->report['totals']['total'][$columnName] -= $row->amount;
}
```

it takes about 11 seconds to process the data and display it

what should i do? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you iterate through some hardcoded or lately-defined number of results. E.g.: Iterate first time through first 200 results, when they are processed, continue with another 200?

Comment: One word: **database**. Sorry for the programming which looks skilled enough for a real programming language.

Comment: Hey Royal - I thought about doing that before asking here, I'll try and update.     Joop - you suggest I'll do these calculations in the query? Or just cache the data?

Comment: I would agree with @Joop, if the data exists in the database anyway then use the database to manipulate the data you want.

Comment: @milkshake, do you have a suggestion on how i should do it?
i make about 20 calculations per row in a different data set

what is the best approach of doing that in sql?

Comment: @sUP its hard to tell without knowing table structure and having some dummy data to test it on, provide that if possible then we can help with the SQL

Comment: @milkshake here is the sql structure:
http://pastie.org/private/exo5zkybi0rjt3fxof6cw


this is the php class that does all the calculations:
http://pastie.org/private/s8o6l6w2sez4zvyht76lg

Comment: @sUP could you use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create the tables with test data in them? then its easier to find a solution.

Comment: @milkshake wow, first of all thank you for introducing me to this great tool! :)

Comment: @sUP no probelm, did you manager to create a sqlfiddle with needed tables and dummy data etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**speed up php only solution**
Apart from the suggested use of a database to organize your stuff, if you still want it the hard way ;) you can avoid iterating (let php do it internaly) over the whole array by using one of the php functions  below:

[array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) 
 — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays

and

[array_walk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) 
 — Apply a user function to every member of an array

I see in your code, you have the 'use' clause, so I presume you are PHP > 5.3. In that case, you can do the following:

```
$yourdata = array_map(
                    function($row) use ($user)
                    { 
                    /*$user->doStuff();*/ 
                    return $row; 
                    }, $yourdata
                    );
```

Furthermore, a lot of overhead is the display rendering part. If you have a lot of things to display, for example using a simple echo, it's faster to do:

```
$result = "";
$result .= $something;
$result .= $somethingelse;
echo $result;
```

than

```
echo $something;
echo $somethingelse;
```

**enhance solution to use database**
But besides that, it will surely be beneficial if you use the database. The most obvious thing is to store your data in some db tables and use some sql-ish solution to query it. It will speed your script up for sure.

**speed up the db+php solution**
Next, you can get a major performance boost by doing most of your calculations (business logic) inside the database engine in form of stored procedures.

For example if you'd go with mysql, you could create a cursor and iterate over your table rows in a loop. On every row you do some stuff, while ofcourse having direct access to all the tables/columns of your scheme (and possibly other stored procedures/functions). If you are doing a lot of math-ish calculations it's a great solution, but ofcourse IMHO it's usually less convenient (more sophisticated) to write your stuff in SQL rather than PHP ;)

Comment: sure thing! :) The performance gain is usually significant when you have your business login written in SQL instead of PHP - it's a great motivator to learn detailed PL/SQL :)

Comment: @Gadoma i can't use native array functions becuase the "array" i'm processing is actually a collection class and each item is an instance of the model. 

about the dabase - i don't have the knowledge of doing so and i don't really have much time to do it now. but just to learn, what should i google? :)

is there any other way do accomplish what i want in PHP? or its a lost cause? 

btw: when i remove all the logic that manipulates $report (the array where i sum all data by several properties), the loading time is ~550ms. 

with the processing (add/subtract items in $report) it takes up to 11s

Comment: @sUP you're welcome! If you feel my post is the solution to your question you can accept it as the correct anwer or upvote it, so in future others can find it and also benefit from your example. Regards,

EDIT:

Are you using any PHP framework ? It'd be a lot easier if you could explain the context of all the processing you try to enhance.

Comment: yeah sorry i wanted to make another line in comment so i hit enter by mistake. i posted my full comment (and still thank you!)

Comment: @sUP can you provide the usage context of the example processing from your initial question ? Are you using any PHP framework, if so which one? Knowing the specifics would help here.

Comment: Server side is Laravel, for the client I use AngularJS.
I print the result array (the array i'm adding and subtracting values) and in angular is put it in a sorted and filtered table

Comment: @sUP Laravel is a wonderful framework, I use it myself, but as for your post - it'd need a broader view of the whole problem your tackling, as the calculations you present are surely part of a more complex system, right?

Comment: @Gadoma after a lot of googling and trying to catch the problem, i think that php is just not fast enough for those things. i reconstructed the class and noticed that when i reduce the number of functions (even if the function is doing nothing) - the load is better. i now have 11k items and it takes ~5s to proccess.

i think about caching report per month\department and calculate the totals.

can you give me more information about the sql way (using mysql)?

Comment: I remember when I was doing some similar stuff back in the day (manipulating large datasets with php) I came across that problem as well. Writing OOPhp to process a lot of stuff is not blazing fast, I agree.What can be done ? You can put your processing stuff in a separate procedural php file and run it from you OO code by fetching it with curl for example. Another way is ofcourse using some caching or storing your subcalculations or in-calculation-objects in some way. Thinking about an sql-oriented solution, try to keep stuff neede for subcalculations in the db as well (just like you wrote)

Comment: I was just writing another comment for you: to sum up our discussion, best solution for you is to rewrite the report-creation logic into the database as stored procedures. I looked at your controller and it seems not to be complicated and is suitable to rewrite into PL/SQL. 
Check out these:  
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx  + 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/

Comment: iv'e read the tutsplus one, but couldn't understand how can i end up with a set of nested arrays.this is the final array structure: http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/1600/0093.png